# "undefined method `find_by'" in Chapter 11 of Michael Hartl's tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I'm getting these 2 errors and I'm not sure how to fix them. One issue I've been running into is the differences between the new version of the tutorial and the old (the difference between rails 4 and 3.2).

My specs are:

Ruby version: 1.9.2p320

Rails version: 3.2.13

Rspec: 2.11.1

Computer: Macbook Pro OS X Mountain Lion

**Errors**

```
  1) User following and unfollowing 
     Failure/Error: before { @user.unfollow!(other_user) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `find_by' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation
     # ./app/models/user.rb:36:in `unfollow!'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User following and unfollowing followed_users 
     Failure/Error: before { @user.unfollow!(other_user) }
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `find_by' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation
     # ./app/models/user.rb:36:in `unfollow!'
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:47:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

**User.rb**

```
  def following?(other_user)
    relationships.where(followed_id: other_user.id).first
  end

  def follow!(other_user)
    relationships.create!(followed_id: other_user.id)
  end

  def unfollow!(other_user)
    relationships.find_by(followed_id: other_user.id).destroy!
  end
```

**user_spec.rb**

```
describe "following" do
    let(:other_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      @user.save
      @user.follow!(other_user)
    end

    it { should be_following(other_user) }
    its(:followed_users) { should include(other_user) }

    describe "followed users" do 
      subject { other_user }
      its(:followers) {should include(@user) } 
    end

    describe "and unfollowing" do
      before { @user.unfollow!(other_user) }

      it {should_not be_following(other_user) }
      its(:followed_users) {should_not include(other_user) }
    end
  end
```

Comment: I would find out why `relationships` is `nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def unfollow!(other_user)
  relationships.find_by_followed_id(other_user.id).destroy!
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`find_by` as you are using it, did not exist in Rails 3. Rails 3 made use of `method_missing` for this, so using `find_by_followed_id` would work.

I recommend using Hartl's [Rails 3 tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book?version=3.2).

Comment: Thanks for that link as well!

Answer (score 0):

As an FYI the find_by_X methods are deprecated with rails 4.  All queries are now Model.find(attribute: "attribute")

Comment: Is this true? I'm pretty sure you need `find_by(attribute: attribute)`.